# How can I bookmark some code in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-7

As in MS Visual Studio, I would like to bookmark some piece of code in a Delphi program and I can't find it in the IDE. With it, I'll be able to find back a piece of code and switch between different files without loosing the exact line where I was working for.

Is it possible within Delphi 7 ?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Bookmarks

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + [0-9] to bookmark

Comment: CTRL + [0-9] goto bookmark

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't able to find it because I didn't know that was called 'bookmark'. Really useful

Comment: Just fYI, some 3rd-party IDE add-ons for D7 such as GExperts provide "persistent" bookmarks, which remain after you close and re-open a project.

Comment: @MartynA I'm using GExperst 1.38 beta, how do I access persistent bookmarks? the Readme states it's a future enhancement..

Comment: Just a heads up that `Ctrl + Shift + 0` can be blocked by Windows Keyboard setting shortcuts. So you may want to disable that particular Windows shortcut.

Comment: @JohnEasley:  Sorry, looks like a slip of my memory & I can't immediately recall which add-on I was thinking of.  Mark Miller's CodeRush used to have them, and Parnassus, but that's not for D7 so far as I know.

Comment: I just use TODO list as "permanent bookmark". Right click on code : -> then choose add todo item. Then You can view it from : View->Todo

Comment: @Vancalar:  Nice "re-purposing" of ToDos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delphi offers up to 10 *bookmarks*, labeled with the numerals 0–9. You can place or remove them in your code by right-clicking a line and choosing the "Toggle Bookmark" menu option, or by using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⟨#⟩</kbd> keyboard shortcut. Navigate to an already-placed bookmark by right-clicking and using the "Go to bookmark" menu item, or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⟨#⟩</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

[The documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Bookmarks) has some more details on the subject.

Comment: Once you have used Delphi bookmarks you will likely miss them in `Visual Studio` or `Visual Studio Code`. Fortunately there are extensions for both. In VS try `VSBookmarks` by Sergey Vinyarsky. And in VS Code try `Numbered Bookmarks` by Alessandro Fragnani.